# Android app doesn't work on Android api level above 20

Tags: android, google-maps, azure, android-manifest, android-api-levels

Release build of an app is perfectly working on Android 4.0.3 and 4.4.2 which api levels are 15 and 19. But when I try to run it on android 5.0.1 and above it shows a grey screen only even without an appbar. I am using Google Maps, Microsoft Azure simple app and support library.

My manifest uses-permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

And my manifest's uses-features

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" />
```

Comment: What are minSdkVersion and maxSdkVersion?

Comment: @DmitriyKaluzhin minSdkVersion - 15, there is no maxSdkVersion, only targetSdkVersion which is 25, and compileSdkVersion is 25.